# Get the row index of bootstrap table in click without using jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-table, react-bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table in my react project. I want to get the index of row which I click on. I want to do something like this onclick = {this.handleClick} and in handleClick function I want to get the index of row. Is it possible to do it. Most of the solutions available shows everything using jquery and I don't want to use Jquery. I want to do it using just javascript only. This is my table

```
<Table className='flags-table' responsive hover>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> </th>
                                            <th> Time In </th>
                                            <th> Time Out </th>
                                            <th> Type </th>
                                            <th> Category </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {
                                            FLAGS_LIST.map((x,i)=> (
                                                <tr key={i}>
                                                    <td> <div className='red-box'></div> </td>
                                                    <td> {x.time_in} </td>
                                                    <td> {x.time_out} </td>
                                                    <td> {x.type} </td>
                                                    <td> {x.category} </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            ))  
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </Table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
onclick = {this.handleClick.bind(this, i)};
```

and `handleClick` should declare like this:

```
var handleClick = function(i) {
console.log("key of row", i)
...
};
```